# Отображение файла .txt NGINX

Tags: nginx, сервер

На сайте не выводилися файл robots.txt, вместо него отображалась ошибка 404
В конфигурацию Nginx добавил следующую настройку

```
`location /robots.txt {
  return 201;
  try_files /var/www/site/data/www/site.com$uri$is_args$args =404;
}`
```

Ошибка 404 пропала, и сервер стал возвращать пустой файл robots.txt (содержимое в нем есть)

Пути прописаны все правильно это точно.
Я не особо разбираюсь в nginx, помогите пожалуйста!!!

Comment: Весь конфиг сервера в студию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Указанный вами location измените следующим образом:

```
location = /robots.txt {
  root /var/www/site/data/www/site.com;
}
```

Если ваш robots.txt расположен по пути /var/www/site/data/www/site.com/robots.txt, то это поможет.

Чтобы предложить оптимальный вариант нужно видеть ваш текущий конфиг.

Comment: Это помогло, спасибо))